# Internationalizing (I18n) my extension, translation file upload error

Tags: utf-8, internationalization, google-chrome-extension

Getting the following error when uploading my extension:

```
An error occurred: Message JSON file must be in UTF-8 encoding.
```

I have about 19 translation files.

When I run the following command locally:

```
file extension/_locales/[locale]/messages.json
```

I get:

```
extension/[locale]/messages.json: UTF-8 Unicode English text
```

On a few locale translations (Polish, Catalonian, Portugese, French, etc..) I get the following message

```
extension/[locale]/messages.json: UTF-8 Unicode English text, with very long lines
```

I have tracked the upload error from the Chrome webstore down to locale translation files that output 'with very long lines' from the 'file' command.

I'm not really sure how to fix this problem. Any advice?

Oh, I should mention the translation files:

- Don't have a BOM
- Contain no comments

UPDATE:

This error was caused by two problems:

- Forgot to remove a comment in one of the locale json files.
- There was a bad character in a few locale files.

Really makes me frustrated that I didn't run into this problem locally during development. C'mon Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is really that the key/values are exceeding some size limit, then you might try breaking up the lines that go over 300 characters onto multiple lines:

```
{
    "longMessage": {
        "message": "This is a really long message 
                   over 300 characters that has 
                   been put on multiple lines"
     }
}
```

See this question for more details on the 300 character limit:

https://superuser.com/questions/91660/how-long-is-long-for-the-unix-file-command

It would be useful to narrow down reproducing this error to just one key/value pair so that you can run this test on that one string as opposed to all of them.  Also, if you are able to narrow it down to just one, then edit you question with the string so I can try locally.

Comment: After re-investigating, the problem was caused by one comment in a locale file and a couple bad characters.